# async- await until someone tries to connect

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, listener, async-await

I want to create an async method that awaits until someone will try to connect
something that will look like

```
await (listener.Pending() == true);
```

of course, that won't work.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async / await or Begin / End with TcpListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187032/async-await-or-begin-end-with-tcplistener)

Comment: Not a strict duplicate. The other question is "which should I use - APM or TAP" this is "how do I wait for a listener (using await)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use async/await then potentially you are using .NET 4.5. If so you can use the [`AcceptSocketAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocketasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`AcceptTcpClientAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods on `TcpListener`? For example:

```
await listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
```

The `Pending` method does the same checks as these two methods but just returns immediately with a `true`/`false`. The two `Accept...Async` are designed to block until `Pending` would otherwise return `true` and then hand you your `Socket` or `TcpClient` respectively.

#### Background

From the [`Pending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation:

> This non-blocking method determines if there are any pending connection requests. Because the AcceptSocket and AcceptTcpClient methods block execution until the Start method has queued an incoming connection request, the Pending method can be used to determine if connections are available before attempting to accept them.

The `Accept...Async` methods do the same as the `Accept...` versions, but you can `await` them.

Comment: should I use that instead the normal AcceptSocket()? like: socket = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync(); I just didn't know about this option. Probably will do the trick, thanks

Comment: `AcceptSocketAsync` is just a convenient async blocking method that will allow you to wait using `await` instead of doing your own tricks to wait for `AcceptSocket` to return a socket.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Task` from `Begin\EndAccept`:

```
var listener = new TcpListener(...);
Task<Socket> acceptTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<Socket>(listener.BeginAcceptSocket, listener.EndAcceptSocket, null);

var socket = await acceptTask;
```

Comment: I like the `FromAsync` helper function, but in .NET 4.5 I would use my answer purely for brevity. It is worth highlighting your answer will work in .NET 4 where mine requires .NET 4.5.

Comment: This exactly what TcpListner does internally.